# Laravel - calling a function which redirect back

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing to ask you about calling functions in laravel. I have a function which is doing something, and in that function I'm calling other function which is checking permissions.

I'm calling the function like: `self::checkPermissions(var1,var2);`

In the **checkPermissions** function I'm checking if user has privileges to something or not. If he has not permissions I'm redirecting him back.`return redirect()->back();`

**The conclusion:** Why the called function cannot redirect user?

Comment: Show your redirect code

Comment: Look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects, use `return back();`

Comment: Return back is not a solution.

Comment: use `return` in your functions

Comment: You are quite annyoing. I'm returning redirection my function.

Comment: How are you calling self::checkPermissions()? You should probably call it `return self::checkPermissions(var1, var2);`.

Comment: Do you use `return` for your function which you are calling it from your controller ? the function inside too ?

Comment: I can't call it like that, because when I will return the checkPermissions function then the rest of the code won't be executed.

Comment: Then, use an if at the end of your method

Comment: I'm just curious why it works like that. Of course I can return false in the checkPermissions function when the user has wrong permissions and then redirect user, but I would like to know the way of how it works.

Comment: You can return a bool instead of redirecting back, so you can redirect back when ever you want.

Comment: I know it. but that's not the answer which I would like to get. And I wrote that over you comment.

Comment: So, You can use non-laravel functions like http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php, but it's not the right way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132374/discussion-between-amiroperator-and-forexknight).

Comment: So if it's not the right why you are suggesting it.

Comment: I suggest you to return a bool and then check it whenever you want. and if want to know more about returns in laravel go read docs.

Comment: Search about `http response laravel`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses

Answer (score 2):

I recommend return `bool` variable from `checkPermissions` function. Something like

```
public function index()
{
    $havePermission = self::checkPermissions(var1, var2);

    if(!$havePermission) return redirect()->back();

    // Else code here
}

private function checkPermissions($var1, $var2)
{
    // return true or false
}
```

Comment: I know that I can do it like that. But it's not the answer on my question. The question is "Why called function cannot redirect user?"

Comment: because It is related with routes. you should learn more about routes and responses.

Comment: Anyway your answer is no the answer I wanted. I understand routes and responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect like that because `redirect()->back()` is a **Response** which returns a laravel response and responses must return to controller which is called by route, so you can redirect user back.